# User commands in TexStudio: how to refer to the current folder?

Tags: texstudio

When I go to TexStudio -> Options -> Configure TexStudio -> Build -> User Commands, I can add arbitrary shell commands. Inside the commands, I can use the character % to refer to the current file name - without extension and without folder. How can I refer to the *folder* of the current file?

The [manual](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02a) says: "If you need more options (e.g. absolute paths) use ? and look at the instruction on the bottom of the configuration dialog." But I did not find these instructions.

Comment: In section 4.4. of the user manual there is a bit more about the ? path selector: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33a

Answer (score 3):

You can use **shell expansions** on the root document's absolute path to get its parent directory: `"$(dirname ?ame")"` (you need to execute this through a shell for expansions to work, e.g. `sh -c 'my-command "$(dirname ?ame")"'`).

Use-case: this is what I do to use [MikTeX](https://miktex.org/) on Ubuntu 22.04 through Docker in TeXstudio (see [Support for Debian 11/Ubuntu 22.04 · Issue #1111 · MiKTeX/miktex](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1111) and [Dockerized MikTeX](https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-docker)):

[image: TeXstudio configuration]

```sh
sh -c 'docker run --rm -v ~/.miktex/:/miktex/.miktex/ -v "$(dirname ?ame")":/miktex/work/ miktex/miktex:latest pdflatex "$(basename ?ame")"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `?a)`

For example, I created a user command which copies the .bib file into the current directory as a user command. I used

```
/home/user/bin/copy_library ?a)
```